# How to pass data through a redirect in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want the user to be able to enter a list of changes into one page, then be redirected to a validation page where they can press accept or reject, and then be redirected back to the original page with the changes made.  My first attempt to do this looks like:

view_event:

```
@bp.route('/<int:event_id>/view_event', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def view_event(event_id):
    #...#
    return redirect(url_for('event.validate_event',
                            event_id=event_id,
                            event_name=event_name,
                            change_list=change_list))
```

validate_event:

```
@bp.route('/<int:event_id>/validate_event', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def validate_event(event_id = None, event_name = None, change_list = None):

    event_id = request.args['event_id']
    event_name = request.args['event_name']
    change_list = request.args['change_list']
    #...#
```

However, when I follow this redirect, I get a 400 Bad Request error.  I don't know if I'm using this correctly or how parameters are supposed to be passed through a redirect.  I'm looking for a solution, as well as how to diagnose the problem in general.

Comment: is it possible that the resulting redirect URL is over 2Kb long?

Comment: If no part is defined within the [variable rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) of the route, then the value is not to be transferred via the attribute of the endpoint and must be requested via [`request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Request.args) as an optional URL parameter.

Comment: @Marat Definitely not in this test case, but I hadn't thought of that and should bear it in mind.  It isn't LIKELY to happen, so it'd probably be sufficient to check for it and return an error if so, but yes, in general it would be possible.

Comment: @Detlef I don't understand, I thought that I was using request.args. How should I be doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're faced with a `BadRequestKeyError`. This occurs when you query a value from a dict that does not exist.

Since you're already extracting the `event_id` inside the rule for the route, it's part of the call to the endpoint. The variable is assumed for the call.

```
@bp.route('/<int:event_id>/validate_event')
@login_required
def validate_event(event_id):
    # ...
```

The other parameters not specified in the route are separated by '?' and '&' appended to the URL and are optional.
For this purpose, it is advisable to query the variables via `request.args`. Since these cannot be assumed, I recommend `request.args.get('event_name')` and `request.args.getlist('change_list')` for a possibly existing sequence to prevent said error message. As a second argument, you can specify a default value if required. If you don't specify this and the requested value is not found within the dictionary, `None` will be returned.

A possible implementation would look like this.

```
@bp.route('/<int:event_id>/validate_event')
@login_required
def validate_event(event_id):
    event_name = request.args.get('event_name')
    change_list = request.args.getlist('change_list')
    # ...
```

In the case of a redirect, the client is asked to send another request to the server. The address is specified in the HTTP header `Location`. The request type (GET or POST) is determined by the satus code, which corresponds to a GET request with 302 by default. A forwarding with POST is rather rare.

Therefore, make sure that your data can be transported within the URL in a way that is visible to third parties.